# Debuggin without compiling webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I have source code which use `webpack`

I need to compile everytime script is changed.

`webpack --config ./webpack/demo.config.ts"`

But it is a bit troublesome when developing.

Is there any good way to test without compiling??

What is the best practice for delopping under `webpack`??

`demo.config.ts`

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as minimist from 'minimist';
import * as path from 'path';

import {baseConfig} from './base.config';

// Allow for specific demos to built with a --demos=<someName>,<someOtherName>
// CLI format.
const args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));
console.log("-------------", args)
const specified: string[] = args.demos ? args.demos.split(',') : [];

const getDemos = source => {
  return fs.readdirSync(source)
      .filter(name => path.extname(name) === '.html' && name !== 'index.html')
      .map(name => path.basename(name, '.html'))
      .filter(demo => specified.length ? specified.includes(demo) : true);
};

const entries = getDemos('./demos').reduce((obj, name) => {
  obj[name] = `./demos/${name}.js`;
  return obj;
}, {});

module.exports = {
  ...baseConfig,
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    ...entries,
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name]_bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../demos'),
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '../demos'),
    port: 8080,
  },
};
```

`base.config.ts`

```
export const baseConfig = {
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.ts$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: 'ts-loader',
    }],
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
};
```

Comment: You need to compile with any changes. You can use [webpack watch](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/) to watch for changes and compile when needed, you can use hotkeys in your development environment to kick it off, etc. If it takes a while, you can look into caching options to speed up the compiling.

Comment: THank you `watch : true ` gives me what I need. With this, compiling is not troublesome.